# rsync: copy symlink realpaths vs. re-create symlinks

Tags: rsync

I have this command now:

```
rsync --copy-links -r src dest
```

this will copy the target files of any symlinks in src and write out copies of those files in dest.

My question is - is there a way to re-create the symlinks with simply a new target (dest)?

I tried

```
rsync --links -r src dest
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

Say my src dir looks like:

```
src/
  foo/
  bar/  # symlinked dir
  baz/
```

Comment: supposedly `--links` should work tho: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I also tried `--copy-dirlinks` this also copied bar instead of copying the symlink

Comment: I can not reproduce this. `rsync -r --links src dest` copies the links.

Answer (score 3):

`--links` is correct.  But if you have previously used `--copy-links`, then it will have created real directories (with content) in the destination.  A later run with `--links` will not be able to remove those directories to replace them with links.

```
$ rsync -r --copy-links src/ dest/ # creates a real directory in /dest
$ ls -l dest
drwxr-xr-x 2 user staff 4096 Dec 18 00:47 bar
```

Now try to copy the links...

```
$ rsync -r --links src/ dest/
cannot delete non-empty directory: bar
could not make way for new symlink: bar
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Oops, not yet.  Need to remove the destination directory first.

```
$ rm -rf dest/bar
$ rsync -r --links src/ dest/
$ ls -l dest
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user staff 6 Dec 18 00:52 bar -> ../bar
```

Comment: hmmm thanks let me try it again, I didn't see the dir show up after the copy